# Filling up dataframe columns based on condition in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-2.7, dataframe

I have two dataframes , like below

```
         df_input                                    df_output
id       POLL_X  POLL_Y  POLL_Z ..     id   Pass_01  Pass_02  Pass_03 .....
110101       1       2       4       110101             
110102       2       1       3       110102
```

and the requirement is to fill up df_ouput based on the value in df_input

```
            df_input                                    df_output
  id   POLL_X  POLL_Y  POLL_Z ....       id   Pass_01  Pass_02  Pass_03 .....
110101     1       2       3            110101     X       Y         Z  
110102     2       1       3            110102     Y       X         Z
```

so basically the column value from the df_input will be the cell value in df_output while matches and based df_input.id == df_output.id

I was trying like below

```
def function1(df_input, number):
       dfwithCols = df_input[df_input.columns[pd.Series(df_input.columns).str.startswith('POLL_')]]
       list_cols = dfwithCols .columns[(dfwithCols == float(number)).iloc[0]]
       colValue = (dfReduced == float(index)).idxmax(axis=1)[0]
       return colValue
```

--driver function---

```
for i in range(1,number_of_columnswithPass):
      df_output['Pass_'+i] = function1(df_input,i)
```

number_of_columnsiwthPass is constant which gives the total number of columns with name as pass .

Also I can not iterate through each row as it will take huge time , have to do it on column based or lambda based

there are other columns in both dataframes , also df_input.id == df_output.id has to be matched

The total number of columns can be around 40 , some test values include POLL_DNW , POLL_DO, POLL_DOES , POLL_SIG:2
so I have to take whatever it is after the '_' and the column numbers like 01,02,03,04----10,11,--21,---39,40

Comment: is it safe to assume that the initial data in df_output are null values?

Comment: yes , it is . null or nan

Comment: but its id column is filled up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that at the start you have *df_output* with proper column names
(as they should be after filling).

To do your task:

1. `import re` (will be used in a moment).
2. Define the following function generating an outpu row, based on a source row:

   ```
   def genRow(row):
       ind = []
       vals = []
       for k, v in row.iteritems():
           mtch = re.match('POLL_(.+)', k)
           if mtch:
               ind.append('Pass_' + str(v).zfill(2))
               vals.append(mtch.group(1))
           else:
               ind.append(k)
               vals.append(v)
       return pd.Series(vals, index=ind).rename(row.name)
   ```

   Note that this function "substitutes" any *POLL_...* column with
   repective *Pass_...* column and leaves other columns as they were.
3. Apply it:

   ```
   df_output = df_input.apply(genRow, axis=1).reindex(columns=df_output.columns)
   ```

Steps:

- `df_input.apply(...)` - Generate a "preliminary" output DataFrame.
  Note that for now the column order is **alphabetical**.
- `reindex(...)` - Reindex the above DataFrame, using column names
  from *df_output*, providing proper order of columns.
- `df_output =` - Overwrite *df_output* with the above result.

## Edit

If your input DataFrame contains repeated values in *POLL_...* columns,
a slight modification is needed.
Such case results in an output row where these two (or more) elemens have
**the same** index, so the whole DataFrame can not be constructed if it
includes such a row.

The remedy is to "compress" such elements into **one** element with the
original index and all values converted to a string, containing e.g.
comma separated list of original values.

To do it, change the last row in *genRow* function to:

```
out = pd.Series(vals, index=ind).rename(row.name)
return out.groupby(lambda key: key).apply(lambda lst: (', '.join(sorted(lst))))
```

Comment: there are other columns in both dataframes , also df_input.id == df_output.id has to be matched

Comment: I corrected my solution to keep the source index. It there are other column to omit, please specify which (how to tell apart columns to process from columns to omit).

Comment: the columns whcih starts with PASS has to be go under this logic , other can stay as it is and the other columns I took care of it anyway

Comment: getting this error while doing your solution   "AttributeError: ("Can only use .str accessor with string values (i.e. inferred_type is 'string', 'unicode' or 'mixed')", 'occurred at index Pass_DNW'

Comment: sure , it can be maximum up to 40 columns , and it can be of any word not just a character . like PASS_DOES , PASS_DNW  , PASS_SIG:2  .  I edited the main question too

Comment: thanks , getting error like  -- ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis

Comment: This error message indicates that the colum names are duplicated.
Look at column lists in the "preliminary" table and in *output_df*.
Maybe your input data contain **the same** number in two *POLL_...*
columns? Then the preliminary DataFrame would contain repetition. Your input sample doesn't include such a case, so I didn't consider it.

Comment: I have checked and did a for loop for each row , and could not find a duplicate value in one row , still I am getting the same error

Comment: Replace the last line as I wrote in the Edit. Then run my code on parts of your input file. Try to locate the row that causes the error.

Answer (score 0):

create two dataframes from df_input and output, merge them and pivot back to get ur final dataframe :

```
#create first dataframe
    res1 = pd.wide_to_long(df,
                       stubnames='Pass',
                       i='id',
                       j='letters',
                       sep='_',
                       suffix='[A-Z]').reset_index()
                          )
res1

     id letters Pass
0   110101  X   1
1   110102  X   2
2   110101  Y   2
3   110102  Y   1
4   110101  Z   4
5   110102  Z   3

#create second dataframe
res2 = (df1
        .melt('id')
        .drop('value', axis=1)
        .assign(numbers=lambda x: x.variable.str.split('_').str.get(-1))
        .astype( {'numbers': int})
       )

res2

      id    variable    numbers
0   110101  Pass_01       1
1   110102  Pass_01       1
2   110101  Pass_02       2
3   110102  Pass_02       2
4   110101  Pass_03       3
5   110102  Pass_03       3

#merge the two dataframes, and pivot to get ur final output

outcome = (res1
           .merge(res2,
                  left_on=['id','Pass'],
                  right_on=['id','numbers'],
                  how='right')
           .pivot(columns='variable',values='letters',index='id')
           .bfill()
           .reset_index()
           .rename_axis(columns=None)
          )

outcome

      id    Pass_01 Pass_02 Pass_03
0   110101     X       Y       Z
1   110102     Y       X       Z
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html), [`unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html#pandas.DataFrame.unstack) and some [`set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and [`reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html#pandas.DataFrame.reset_index) to play with which columns are in the logic.

```
df2 = (df1.set_index('id') #set index any columns not in the logic of pass
          # remove the prefix Pass_
          .rename(columns=lambda col: col.replace('Pass_', ''))
          # stack the datafrae to make it a serie and sort the passes
          .stack().sort_values()
          # next two method exchange the old pass index to the new pass index
          .reset_index(level=1, name='Pass')
          .set_index('Pass', append=True)['level_1']
          # from the serie to the dataframe shape
          .unstack()
          # rename the columns with the prefix pass_
          .rename(columns=lambda col: f'Pass_{col:02}')
          # rename axis to none
          .rename_axis(None, axis=1)
          # but back the id as a column
          .reset_index())

print (df2)
       id Pass_01 Pass_02 Pass_03
0  110101       X       Y       Z
1  110102       Y       X       Z
```

Note: if you have other columns you don't want to include in the process, then set them as index with id at first like `set_index(['id','col1', ...])`